# Sql query to select ID from 100 to 140

Tags: mysql, sql

I need sql query to select the iDs(particularly 100 to 140) from the table..

exact ids identification from_id to to_id

Thanks in advance

Comment: `WHERE ID BETWEEN 100 AND 140`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

```
Select * FROM YourTable WHERE  ID BETWEEN 100 AND 140
```

OR

```
Select * FROM YourTable WHERE  ID > 100 AND ID < 140
```